# Ldap Login in angular js + Express+ passport-ldapauth + sails application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js

We have a website which has to be authenticated with windows active directory. I am using passport-ldapauth as middleware.

Authentication does not proceed ahead and whenever I click the submit button the following message gets printed to the console.

{Message : 'Missing credentials'}

this is the code:

login.jade

```
.login-form(ng-controller="LoginCtrl")
  form
    input(type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Enter employee number")
    input(type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password")
    button.show-bu-btn.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="submit()") Submit
```

logincontroller.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('someapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, Service) {

  $scope.submit = function () {


      $http.post('/Login', {uname: $scope.username}).success(function (res) {
        console.log('login OK ', res);

        sessionStorage.userAccessInfo = JSON.stringify(res.userAccessInfo);
        sessionStorage.dataQuery = JSON.stringify(res.userAccessInfo);
        location.hash = '#/main';

      }).error(function (res) {
      });

  };

});
```

routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {

  'post /Login' : 'AuthController.process',

};
```

AuthController.js

```
module.exports = {
process: function(req, res) {
      var emp = req.body.uname;

        Acl.findOne({empid: emp}).exec(function(err, user) {
          //console.log(user);
            if(user) {

                passport.authenticate('ldapauth', function(err, user, info) {
                    console.log(info);                
                    if(err || !user) {

                        return res.redirect('/login');
                    }

                    req.logIn(user, function(err)
                    {

                        if (err)
                        {

                            res.redirect('/login');
                            return;
                        }


                    });
                })(req, res);
            } 

            else {
              res.json({userAccessInfo: undefined});
              //console.log('Something is wrong');  
          }
        });
    }
};
```

Acl.js
Data resides in a flat file

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    empid: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'empid'
    },
    designation: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'designation'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'email'
    }
  }
};
```

Passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var express = require('express');
var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth').Strategy;
var app = express();


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Acl.findOne({id:id}).exec(function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(
    new LdapStrategy({
        server: {
            url: 'ldap://xxxx.xx.xx:389',
            adminDn: 'serviceadmin',
            adminPassword: 'servicepassword',
            searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})',
            searchBase: 'DC=xxxx,DC=xx,DC=xx'

        },
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
        function(user, done) {

            if(!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
            }
            Acl.findOne({username:user.uid}).exec(function(err,user) {

                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    )
);
```

Any ideas on why I am getting the message are highly appreciated. Please correct if there is some mistake.